# Calculate $\iiiint_{x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2\leq 1}e^{x^2+y^2-u^2-v^2}\,dx\,dy\,du\,dv$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

$$\iiiint_{x^2+y^2+u^2+v^2\leq 1}e^{x^2+y^2-u^2-v^2}\,dx\,dy\,du\,dv$$

So we just learned substitution and i thought maybe for this integral doing 2 polar subs for x,y and for u,v but i'm not sure this is the right way for this.
Any hints will be welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with what you said, we'll just have to do an additional substitution afterwards. Let

$$\begin{cases} x = r\cos\theta \\ y = r\sin\theta \\ u = s\cos \phi \\ v = s\sin\phi \\ \end{cases} \implies J = rs$$

which gives us the integral

$$\int_{r^2+s^2\leq 1 \:\cap\:(\theta,\phi)\in[0,2\pi]^2} rse^{r^2-s^2}\:dr\:ds\:d\theta\:d\phi = 4\pi^2\int_{r^2+s^2\leq 1} rs e^{r^2-s^2}\:dr\:ds$$

Now let

$$\begin{cases}r = \rho \cos\gamma \\ s = \rho \sin\gamma \\ \end{cases} \implies J = \rho$$

giving us the integral

$$4\pi^2 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \rho^3\sin\gamma\cos\gamma \: e^{\rho^2(\cos^2\gamma - \sin^2\gamma)}\:d\gamma\:d\rho = \pi^2 \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 2\rho^3\sin2\gamma \:e^{\rho^2\cos2\gamma} \:d\gamma\:d\rho$$

since $r,s>0$ by definition. Integrating gives us

$$\pi^2 \int_0^1-\rho \:e^{\rho^2\cos2\gamma}\Bigr|_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\:d\rho = \pi^2 \int_0^1 2\rho\:\sinh(\rho^2) \:d\rho = \pi^2(\cosh 1 - 1)$$